# Calling a getAverage method within another class, on an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I have a class that has some methods, ArrayMin, ArrayMax, ArrayAvg, and a constructor that generates an array of 10 values with numbers between 0-100.

I am not stuck on actually USING the three methods mentioned above. How do I call the methods and get an average, min, and max? I thought I could just do `a1.ArrayMax()`after creating `Array a1 = new Array(10)`within my MAIN, but no luck.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Array {

    public int size, avg;

    public int ArraySize() {
        return size;
    }

    public int ArrayMin(int a[]) {
        int min = a[0];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
            if (a[i] < min) {
                min = a[i];
            }
        }

        return min;
    }
    public int ArrayMax(int a[]) {

        int max = a[0];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
            if (a[i] > max) {
                max = a[i];
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    public int ArrayAvg(int a[]) {

      int sum = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          sum += a[i]; 
      }
      avg = sum / a.length; 
      return avg;
    }

    public Array(int size) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int min = 0, max = 100;
        int[] a = new int[size];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            int result = rand.nextInt(max-min) + min;
            a[i] = result;
            System.out.println(a[i]);

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the main as well :) And please name your methods properly (camel case notation) it's much harder to read them this way :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing many fundamental principles of OOP, but to specifically address your issue, the int array you create in your constructor is not the same array used in your methods.

To solve this, in your Array class, you need an instance variable to hold this array:

`private int[] a;`

Now that you have this variable, in your constructor instead of doing

`int[] a = ...`

you just do

`a = ...`

To have that instance variable be the one that holds 10 random numbers. You can now remove the parameter in each of your methods to make things work swimmingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor a bit:

```
class Array {

    public static int arrayMin(int a[]) {
        int min = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] < min) {
                min = a[i];
            }
        }

        return min;
    }

    public static int arrayMax(int a[]) {

        int max = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > max) {
                max = a[i];
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    public static int arrayAvg(int a[]) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += a[i];
        }
        return sum / a.length;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int size = 10;
        int min = 0, max = 100;
        int[] a = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int result = rand.nextInt(max - min) + min;
            a[i] = result;
        }

        System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println("Max: " + Array.arrayMax(a));
        System.out.println("Min: " + Array.arrayMin(a));
        System.out.println("Avg: " + Array.arrayAvg(a));
    }
```

output:

```
Array: [96, 56, 21, 59, 85, 31, 84, 83, 23, 80]
Max: 96
Min: 21
Avg: 61
```